# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type xxx

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, collections, datagridview

I want to acces my `Player` object in my `DataGridView`.
This is how I'm binging my Players list to `DataGridView`:

```
PlayerList = new List<Player>(players);
//Populate Player list heere (...)          
DataTable dt = Tools.ToDataTable<Player>(PlayerList);
Grid.DataSource = dt;
```

And now I want to access my `Player` object in selected row in Double click event:

```
private void Grid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (Grid.SelectedCells == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    int row = Grid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

    //Here I get that exception from the title
    ((Player)(Grid.Rows[row].DataBoundItem)).KillPlayer();    
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but I assume that by converting the `List` to `DataTable`, you lose the actual `Player` instance - try accessing the instance directly with `PlayerList[row].KillPlayer();` and see if it works.

Comment: This depends heavily on what Tools.ToDataTable does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   Player player = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Player;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, do you really need to convert to a DataTable?

You should be able to bind the `PlayerList` directly to `Grid.DataSource` via `Grid.DataSource = PlayerList;`

```
PlayerList = new List<Player>(players);
//Populate Player list heere (...)          
Grid.DataSource = PlayerList;
```

Your code `((Player)(Grid.Rows[row].DataBoundItem)).KillPlayer();` should then work fine.

Comment: Yes. I need to use data table. I need sorting.

Comment: Have you considered/tried adding a typed dataset onto your form and setting the Grid DataSource to that, then populating that DataSet rather than `PlayerList`. That should do what you need.

Comment: You can sort other data structures too, you know.